# Execute AzurePowerShell via BICEP Script with External Parameters

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to enable CDN-managed HTTPS on a custom domain via BICEP. The only way to do this is by running an AzurePowerShell command inline within the BICEP code.

I'm struggling with creating a correct power shell command to pass parameters from the BICEP code.

**Example **

This generates error:

> The provided script failed with the following error:
> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term
> 'param' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script
> file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
> path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I'm following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep#use-inline-scripts) where param is used.

```
 var ResourceGroupName = 'xx-Bicep-xxx-Build-Work'
 var ProfileName = profile.name
 var EndpointName = endpoint.name
var CustomDomainName = dnsCnameRecordCnd
    
    var ScriptContent = '''
    param([string] $ResourceGroupName)
    param([string] $ProfileName)
    param([string] $EndpointName)
    param([string] $CustomDomainName)
    $customDomainHttpsParameter = New-AzCdnManagedHttpsParametersObject -CertificateSourceParameterCertificateType Dedicated -CertificateSource Cdn  -ProtocolType ServerNameIndication
    Enable-AzCdnCustomDomainCustomHttps -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ProfileName $ProfileName -EndpointName $EndpointName -CustomDomainName $CustomDomainName -CustomDomainHttpsParameter $customDomainHttpsParameter -SubscriptionId xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx
    '''
    
    resource SetServicesCertificates 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
      name: 'SetServicesCertificates'
      location: location
      kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
      properties: {
        arguments: '-ProfileName ${ProfileName} -EndpointName ${EndpointName} -ResourceGroupName ${ResourceGroupName} -CustomDomainName ${CustomDomainName}'
        azPowerShellVersion: '8.3'
        scriptContent: ScriptContent
        cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
        retentionInterval: 'P1D'
        timeout: 'PT3M'
      }
      dependsOn:[
        UpdateExistingDnsZoneCdn
        endPointCustomDomain
      ]
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You only need "Param" once.  The parameter are handled as an array.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#static-parameters

Comment: Yes - you're confusing bicep `param` with powershell `param` (which is understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to correctly use param per one of the comments. (as an array)

I also needed to create and assign a user identity to execute the script. The new user identity needed CDN Contributor role assigned also.

```
var ScriptContent = '''
   param (
    [string]$ProfileName,
    [string]$EndpointName,
    [string]$ResourceGroupNamea,
    [string]$CustomDomainName
)   
   $customDomainHttpsParameter = New-AzCdnManagedHttpsParametersObject -CertificateSourceParameterCertificateType Dedicated -CertificateSource Cdn  -ProtocolType ServerNameIndication
   Enable-AzCdnCustomDomainCustomHttps -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupNamea -ProfileName $ProfileName -EndpointName $EndpointName -CustomDomainName $CustomDomainName -CustomDomainHttpsParameter $customDomainHttpsParameter -SubscriptionId xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   '''

   resource SetServicesCertificates 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' =  {
    name: 'SetCdnTLS${deploymentName}${resourceSuffix}'
    location: location
    kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
    identity: {
     type: 'UserAssigned'
     userAssignedIdentities: {
       '${managedidentity.id}' : {}
     }
   }
    properties: {
      arguments: '-ProfileName ${profile.name} -EndpointName ${endpoint.name} -ResourceGroupNamea "xx-Bicep-xx-Build-Work" -CustomDomainName ${dnsCnameRecordCnd}'
      azPowerShellVersion: '9.0'
      scriptContent: ScriptContent
      cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
      retentionInterval: 'P1D'
      timeout: 'PT10M'
    }
    dependsOn:[
     roles
     endPointCustomDomain
     UpdateExistingDnsZoneCdn
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell arguments in the script differ from bicep parameters. That is why you're getting the error *"PowerShell command is not recognized."*

When providing parameters from the Bicep code to the PowerShell script, there is no need of declaring `param` blocks in Bicep.

To resolve this, remove the `param` blocks from your script. Instead, Use `arguments` property to pass the parameters. The parameters will be provided to the script automatically with the `arguments` property.

*I modified your deployment script as below and it worked as expected.*

```bash
var ResourceGroupName = 'xxxx'
var ProfileName = 'cdn'
var EndpointName = 'endptest'
var CustomDomainName = 'customdomain'
param location string = 'eastus'
var ScriptContent = '''
   $customDomainHttpsParameter = New-AzCdnManagedHttpsParametersObject -CertificateSourceParameterCertificateType Dedicated -CertificateSource Cdn  -ProtocolType TLS12
   Enable-AzCdnCustomDomainCustomHttps -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ProfileName $ProfileName -EndpointName $EndpointName -CustomDomainName $CustomDomainName -CustomDomainHttpsParameter $customDomainHttpsParameter -SubscriptionId xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx
   '''
   
resource SetServicesCertificates 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = 
{
     name: 'SetServicesCertificates'
     location: location
     kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
     properties: {
       arguments: '-ProfileName ${ProfileName} -EndpointName ${EndpointName} -ResourceGroupName ${ResourceGroupName} -CustomDomainName ${CustomDomainName}'
       azPowerShellVersion: '8.3'
       scriptContent: ScriptContent
       cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
       retentionInterval: 'P1D'
       timeout: 'PT3M'
     }
 }
```

***Output:***

[image]